# Inicio de sesión funciona en XAMPP pero no en el hosting ¿Alguna solución?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, xampp

he estado haciendo una pequeña aplicación de interés académico en PHP con un formulario de login, el cual el XAMPP me trabaja a la perfección, pero cuando subí al hosting no me funcionó.

Mi formulario es el siguiente

```
<div class="bg-form">
      <form id="loginForm" action="ValidarCode.php" method="POST">
        <H5 class="grey-text center-align">Iniciar Sesión</H5>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="usuario" type="text" class="validate" name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Ingrese su cedula aquí" required autofocus>
      <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="contraseña" type="password" class="validate" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña aquí" required >
      <label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <button class="btn bg-btn" type="submit"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Ingresar</button> 
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

mi archivo conexión es el siguiente

```
<?php

class Conexion{

/**
 * Conexión a la base de datos
 * @return Conexion
 */

public static function conectar(){

    try {

        $cn = new PDO("mysql:host=******;dbname=********","*******","********");

        return $cn;

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

y mi validarDatos.php el siguiente

```
<?php

 include 'controlador/UsuarioControlador.php';
include 'helps/helps.php';

session_start(); 

header('Content-type: application/json');

$resultado = array();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (isset($_POST["txtUsuario"]) && isset($_POST["txtPassword"])) {
$txtUsuario = validar_campo($_POST["txtUsuario"]);
$txtPassword = validar_campo($_POST["txtPassword"]);

$resultado = array("estado"=>"true");



if (UsuarioControlador::login("$txtUsuario", "$txtPassword")){

    $usuario = UsuarioControlador::getUsuario("$txtUsuario", "$txtPassword");
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = array(
        "id"=> $usuario->getId(),
        "nombre"=> $usuario->getNombre(),
        "usuario"=> $usuario->getUsuario(),
        "cadena"=> $usuario->getCadena(),
        "privilegio"=> $usuario->getPrivilegio(),
    );
    return print(json_encode($resultado));
}

}
}

$resultado = array("estado"=>"false");
return print(json_encode($resultado));
```

Cuando lo subí al hosting me arrojó el siguiente código en la consola

```
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>/srv/disk8/2028662/www/turnapp.conaccion.co/datos/UsuarioDao.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method UsuarioControlador::getUsuario() should not be called statically in            <b>/srv/disk8/2028662/www/turnapp.conaccion.co/vista/ValidarCode.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>/srv/disk8/2028662/www/turnapp.conaccion.co/datos/UsuarioDao.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>/srv/disk8/2028662/www/turnapp.conaccion.co/datos/UsuarioDao.php</b> on line <b>63</b><br />
{"estado":"true"}
```

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal y si alguien puede ayudarme a corregirlo.

Gracias a la respuesta de un usuario que me dijo que el error venía de un archivo llamado UsuarioDao.php paso a compartir el código de este:

```
<?php

include 'Conexion.php'; 
include '../entidades/Usuario.php';

class UsuarioDao extends Conexion
{
    protected static $cnx;

    private static function getConexion(){
    self::$cnx = Conexion::conectar();
}

    private static function desconectar(){
    self::$cnx = null;
}
/**
 * Metodo que sirve para validad login
 * @param object $usuario  
 * @return boolean 
 */

public static function login($usuario)
{
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password ";

    self::getConexion();

    $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);

    $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
    $resultado->bindParam(":password", $usuario->getPassword());

    $resultado->execute(); 

    if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
        $filas = $resultado->fetch();
        if ($filas["usuario"] == $usuario->getUsuario()
            && $filas["password"] == $usuario->getPassword()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
/**
 * Metodo que sirve para obtener un usuario 
 * @param object $usuario  
 * @return object  
 */

public static function getUsuario ($usuario)
{
    $query = "SELECT id,nombre,usuario,cadena,password,fecha_registro
    FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password ";

    self::getConexion();

    $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);

    $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
    $resultado->bindParam(":password", $usuario->getPassword());

    $resultado->execute(); 

    $filas = $resultado->fetch();

    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $usuario->setId($filas["id"]);
    $usuario->setNombre($filas["nombre"]);
    $usuario->setUsuario($filas["usuario"]);
    $usuario->setCadena($filas["cadena"]);
    $usuario->setPassword($filas["password"]);
    $usuario->setFecha_registro($filas["fecha_registro"]);






    return $usuario;
}

}
```

Comment: Viendo los mensajes de error pensaría que tu hosting tiene PHP 7 instalado y tú hiciste el programa en local en PHP 5 o anterior. Resulta que PHP 5 permitía algunas malas prácticas que ahora PHP 7 no te permite, de ahí errores como: `<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method UsuarioControlador::getUsuario() should not be called statically in   ...</b> `  o sea, `getUsuario()` no es un método `static` en `UsuarioControlador` y tú lo intentas usar como tal. Entonces o lo cambias a estático o instancias la clase y lo llamas desde la instancia creada.

Comment: El error hace referencia a errores en el archivo UsuarioDao.php pero usted no puso el código

Comment: Para detalles sobre lo dicho en mi anterior comentario ver **[Cambios en la severidad de avisos `E_STRICT`](http://php.net/manual/es/migration70.incompatible.php)**. Y en cuanto al otro mensaje, `Only variables should be passed by reference...` revisa en las líneas indicadas lo que estás pasando, si pasas algo que no es variable por referencia, usando `&` delante, debes quitarlo. Otra cosa extraña en tu código es esto: `login("$txtUsuario", "$txtPassword")` y `getUsuario("$txtUsuario", "$txtPassword")`  ... las variables **no deberían ir entre comillas** para pasarlas a un método/función.

Comment: @A.Cedano el hosting estaba en 5.4 y lo pasé a 5.6 que es la versión de xampp que tengo, verifiqué que no estuviese en 7 porque sabía que no funcionaría, ya lo había probado en mamp con esa versión y no funcionó, lo hice siguiendo una serie de videos de una persona, una especie de curso.

Comment: @Ale olvidé subirlo, sin embargo ya lo agregué.

Comment: De todos modos no debes ignorar las advertencias y corregir el código pues tarde o temprano tendrás que pasar a PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

## Only variables should be passed by reference

Como te dice el error, sólo las variables se pueden pasar como referencia. No puedes pasar una clase como referencia, ni la salida de un método como referencia.

El método `bindParam` espera una variable, pero cuando haces

```
$resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
$resultado->bindParam(":password", $usuario->getPassword());
```

El segundo argumento no es una variable. Seguramente lo que quieres hacer es:

```
$resultado->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario->getUsuario());
$resultado->bindValue(":password", $usuario->getPassword());
```

Por otro lado, no estás mostrando el código de `UsuarioControlador`. En tu llamado a

```
UsuarioControlador::getUsuario(texto, texto)
```

No se entiende en qué momento ese llamado delega a

```
UsuarioDao::getUsuario($usuario)
```

Puesto que la primera le pasa usuario y password como string mientras las segunda espera un objeto con métodos `getUsuario` y `getPassword`. ¿De dónde salen esos métodos? O más específicamente, cómo conviertes el texto a una instancia/objeto? Cabe suponer que `UsuarioControlador::login` o `UsuarioControlador::getUsuario` instancian una clase que a su vez se le pasa a `UsuarioDao::login` y `UsuarioDao::getUsuario`. Pero me queda la duda. Uno de estos métodos o ambos tienen que instanciar algo para que en la llamada a `UsuarioDao` puedas usar `getUsuario` y `getPassword` como métodos no estáticos.

## Non static method ... should not be called as static...

De nuevo, no nos mostraste la clase `UsuarioControlador` pero claramente en éste el método `getUsuario` no es un método estático. Posiblemente baste con declarar el método como `public static`

## porqué en tu local funciona y en el remoto tira errores?

Ahora... porqué en tu local funciona y en el remoto tira errores? Una posibilidad es que **las versiones de PHP sean distintas**.

Si tu local está en PHP 5.6 y tu remoto estaba en PHP 5.4, vale la pena comentar que el uso de métodos no estáticos como estáticos [arroja un tipo de error distinto en PHP 5.4 y PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php) (`E_DEPRECATED` en PHP 5.6 y `E_STRICT` en PHP 5.4). Dada esa diferencia de versiones, puede que tanto tu local como tu remoto tengan:

```
E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE
```

Lo cual significa que:

1. En tu local se genera un error E_DEPRECATED suprimido por tu error reporting level
2. En tu remoto el error es en cambio de tipo E_STRICT que no está suprimido el el error reporting level

Otra posibilidad es que tengas **distinta configuración de error_reporting**. Por ejemplo, que en tu local tengas un nivel de errores que suprime los errores `E_STRICT`

```
E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

Y en tu remoto los `E_STRICT` no estén explícitamente omitidos:

```
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

En un comentario pusiste que actualizaste el remoto a PHP 5.6. En ese caso el mensaje de error debiera haber cambiado de:

```
Strict Standards:  Non-static method UsuarioControlador::getUsuario() should not be called statically...
```

A

```
Deprecated:  Non-static method UsuarioControlador::getUsuario() should not be called statically...
```

Confírmanos eso a ver si ayuda a resolver el problema

**Cómo solucionarlo?**

Sea como sea, la solución **no es** apagar los errores `E_STRICT` o `E_DEPRECATED` en tu  local ni remoto, sino habilitarlos en ambos y solucionar la manera como llamas a `UsuarioControlador::getUsuario()` ya sea declarando el método como estático o bien instanciando `UsuarioControlador`.

Esto último de nuevo no lo puedo adivinar sin ver la estructura de `UsuarioControlador` puesto que el uso de `UsuarioControlador::login` no parece arrojar errores. Todo me huele un poco a que tienes funcionalidades duplicadas en `UsuarioControlador` y `UsuarioDao`, con la diferencia que uno espera login y password como argumentos y el otro espera una instancia de `Usuario` como argumento.

Comment: En el último apartado sería más conciso indicando que *Strict Standards* es debido a un error de tipo `E_STRICT` (que a partir de 5.4.0 forma parte de `E_ALL`) y dependiendo de la configuración de [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-reporting) aparecerán estos mensajes o no. Pero son mensajes no críticos, por lo que la ejecución del programa continúa esté activada su visualización o no (aunque no solucionarlos lleve a problemas o a un mal funcionamiento).

Comment: Además (http://php.net/language.oop5.static): ***Advertencia***
*En PHP 7, llamar a métodos no estáticos de forma estática está obsoleto y generará una advertencia `E_DEPRECATED`. **El soporte para las llamadas a métodos no estáticos de forma estática podría ser eliminado en el futuro**.*

Comment: @OscarGarcia es en [PHP 5.6 que pasan a ser E_DEPRECATED](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php) . Significa que en su local puede tener `E_ALL  & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE` y en el remoto,  `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`, por ejemplo. Pero tienes un buen punto: si el error se tipifica como `Strict Standards` y no como `Deprecated` cabe inferir que el remoto usa PHP 5.4

Comment: Con el segundo comentario quería hacer alusión a que no arreglarlo conllevará en que un día deje de funcionar y se considere error crítico y se detenga la ejecución del script. Agrega estas cosas a ti respuesta y más tarde borro los comentarios para dejarte limpio el patio ;)

Comment: En realidad sin saber la forma de `UsuarioController` sólo puedo sugerir declarar los métodos como `public static`. Pero editaré la explicación del comportamiento distinto en el local y el remoto

Comment: @OscarGarcia no me había fijado que el usuario dijo tener PHP 5.6 en el local y PHP 5.4 en el remoto. Ahí está la explicación: debe tener suprimidos los `E_DEPRECATED` y en el remoto no son `E_DEPRECATED` sino `E_STRICT`. Pero además puso que actualizó el remoto a 5.6, por lo que el mensaje de error debiera haber cambiado (o incluso haber desaparecido, lo cual no es algo bueno, para nada)